# as3 remove children in loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm working in Flash CS6 with Adobe AIR 3.3 and having trouble deleting movie clips after I have added them to the stage.  Here's my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i<starCount; i++)
{
    star = new newStar();
    choiceBoard.addChild(star);
    star.x = 195;
    if(i>=1)
    {
        star.x = 195 + 90*i;
    }
    star.y = 597
}
```

This is part of a function I've created that adds star shaped movie clips dynamically...It adds a movie clip, adds space between, adds the next movie clip etc.  How can I delete all the star movie clips after they are created?

I've tried:

```
for(var i = 0; i<starCount; i++)
{
    if(contains(star))
    {
        choiceBoard.removeChild(star);
        trace("removed star");
    }
}
```

But this only deletes one star, regardless what "starCount" is set to.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
private var stars:Array=[];
for(var i = 0; i<starCount; i++)
{
    star = new newStar();
    stars.push(star);
    choiceBoard.addChild(star);
    star.x = 195 + 90*i;
    star.y = 597
}
```

then try

```
for(var i = 0; i<stars.length; i++)
{
    choiceBoard.removeChild(stars[i]);
    trace("removed star");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the stars they only children of choiceBoard? If so, you can just remove all children like so:

```
choiceBoard.removeChildren();
```

Alternatively, you can add all the stars to an array and then iterate through the array to remove them:

```
var starArray:Array = [];

//...

for(var i = 0; i<starCount; i++)
{
    star = new newStar();
    //put the star into the array
    starArray.push(star);
    choiceBoard.addChild(star);
    star.x = 195;
    if(i>=1)
    {
        star.x = 195 + 90*i;
    }
    star.y = 597
}
```

And then to remove:

```
for(var i = 0; i<starArray.length; i++)
{        
    //remove the star from the display
    choiceBoard.removeChild(starArray[i]);      
    trace("removed star");
}
//clear the array
starArray = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added all your stars into one container (looks like you have with `choiceBoard`), and there is nothing else in that container that you want to keep around, then you can remove them very simply (and quickly) by doing this:

```
while(choiceBoard.numChildren)
{
    choiceBoard.removeChildAt(0);
}
```